# How to convert Piecewise function to Interpolation function?

Tags: function-construction, interpolation

In the following piece of code I am trying to convert a `Piecewise` function to a simple interpolation function `f[t_]`

```
T=10000    
 f[t_] := FunctionInterpolation[
          Piecewise[{{0, 0 <= t <= T/4}, {1 - Sin[2*\[Pi]*t/T], 
             T/4 <= t <= 3*T/4}, {2, 3*T/4 <= t <= T}}], {t, 0, T}, 
          InterpolationOrder -> 10]
```

However

1. I was not able to plot it: `Plot[f[t], {t, 0, T}]` resulted in

   > > FunctionInterpolation::range: Argument {0.817143,0,T} is not in the form of a range specification, {x, xmin, xmax}.
2. I was not able to configure `WorkingPrecision`: when adding `...WorkingPrecision -> 20]`, `WorkingPrecision` comes in red.

Can anyone help?

Comment: What is T ? Without its numerical value Plot cannot plot.

Comment: Actually I forgot `T` but your answer is great: it is more practical to have `T` as a parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little large for a comment: Change the function definition as:

```
f[t_, T_] := 
 FunctionInterpolation[
  Piecewise[{{0, 0 <= t <= T/4}, {1 - Sin[2*\[Pi]*t/T], 
     T/4 <= t <= 3*T/4}, {2, 3*T/4 <= t <= T}}], {t, 0, T}, 
  InterpolationOrder -> 10]
```

Now this yields an Interpolation function.

```
f[t, 10]
```

And can be plotted.

```
Plot[f[t, 10][x], {x, 0., 10.}]
```

[image]

Comment: And what about `Working Precision`?

Comment: Where were you adding the WorkingPrecision option ?

Comment: Well, I tried in the end of the `FunctionInterpolation` block, I mean `FunctionInterpolation[...bla,bla,bla,....,WorkingPrecision->100]`. That is how it works for `NDSolve` or `Plot` however it does now work for `FunctionInterpolation`.

Comment: That is because WorkingPrecision is not a valid option for FunctionInterpolation. See Options[FunctionInterpolation]

Comment: Ok, then this should be discussed in a seperate question. Thanks for your help!